# Swagger cpprest third party

Tags: c++, rest

I'm trying to test the basic petstore example with a nodejs server and a cpp client. When trying to build the project with `cmake`, I have the following error:

```
Failed to find cpprest SDK (or missing components).  Double check that
  "CPPREST_ROOT" is properly set
```

At line 39 of `CMakeLists.txt`, I have:

```
#set(CPPREST_ROOT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../developmentTools/3rdParty/cpprest)"
```

Which third party `cpprest` library should I use?

Comment: There only is one project called cpprest sdk afaik, so I don't really understand your question.

Comment: This one? https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk

Comment: That's the only one that came up on google and ddg for me, so should be right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following CPP Rest SDK:

[Microsoft/cpprestsdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk)

Use following command to build you project:

```
cmake -D CPPREST_ROOT=/usr .
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one cpprest project: https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk